# what time does the special events start on tiny death star?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I just found out about these, and i missed last Monday's event. so what time does it start so i don't miss out? I tried finding it online but never found out anything.

Answer (score 1):

There is no advance notice or published schedule. Keep the game up to date and play daily and you won't miss the next one.